# Randperm in iOS

Tags: ios

I know in Matlab, there is a function called randperm, which basically returns a random permutation of the numbers.

For example, randperm(6) returns [3  2  6  4  1  5].

Is there anything similar to that in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so:

```
- (NSArray*) randperm: (int) total
{
   NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < total) {
        NSNumber *randomInteger = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random_uniform(total)+1)];
        if (![array containsObject:randomInteger]) {
            [array addObject:(randomInteger)];
            counter++;
        }

    }
   return array;
}
```

Comment: @gaussblurinc what do u mean?

Comment: NSNumber::(numberWithInteger:) method uses NSInteger as number `seed`. you don't know where your code could fail if you use primitives like `int`. NSInteger is supported alternative to `int` primitive

Comment: As pointed out in a comment to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527185/incompatible-integer-to-pointer-conversion-initializing-nsarray), this code will cause an infinite loop.  There is also no need to make a copy of the array before returning it.