# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing NSArray *

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am running the code like this and it is returning me this error:

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing NSArray *_strong with an expression of type 'int'.
```

The code is like this:

```
- (NSArray *)randperm:(int)total
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < total) {
        NSNumber *randomInteger = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random_uniform(total)+1)];
        if (![array containsObject:randomInteger]) {
            [array addObject:(randomInteger)];
            counter++;
        }

    }
    NSArray *arr = [array copy];
    return arr;
}
```

I am calling it this:

```
NSArray *array = randperm(6);
```

This line is returning me an error. Not sure why there is a such an error.

Comment: Calling randperm with parameter 6 will lead to a infinite loop.

Comment: Because he is generating numbers between 1-4 and checking if the number already exists. After 1-2-3-4 are generated, it won't be able to exit from `while(counter<total)` loop.

Comment: @ugur Yes good point :)

Comment: @ugur made a very stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Fixed the infinite loop error. Hope you didn't mind. Reading code that doesn't work is a pet peeve of mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the Objective-C method as if it was C:

```
NSArray *array = randperm(6);
```

It should be:

```
NSArray *array = [self randperm:6];
```

Also there is no need to make a copy of the array before returning it:

```
NSArray *arr = [array copy];
return arr;
```

Just do:

```
return array;
```

Comment: Copying the array before returning can actually be a good idea. It ensures that an immutable array is returned instead of a mutable array.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for your problem is calling like this :

```
NSArray *array = [self randperm:6];
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the two answers above try changing :

```
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)]
```

to

```
 [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)]
```

because `arc4random_uniform` is returning an `unsigned int`.

Comment: FYI - this should be a comment since it makes no attempt to answer the question.